# Why does running an Action inside update() crashes the application?

Tags: crash, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Good day,

The scenario is this, I have 3 sprites and I want to execute actions to them using sequence, inside the **update()**.
Another thing if the sprite is still executing the action, it will not acquire new action but if it is done executing the action it will create a new action then execute it.

I used **.isDone()** for the checking.

**Here is the pseudo code:**

***-Legend for readability:***
**SampleSprite** - assuming that this is the array of sprites. **isStillOnAction** - boolean, *true* if currently executing action, *false* if not.
**RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5** - is a random number from 2 to 5.

```
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++){
if(!SpriteSample[ctr].isStillOnAction)          // not currently executing action, so we can now assign an action
{
    SampleSprite[ctr].isStillOnAction = true;   // the isStillOnAction boolean is changed to true

    if(SampleSprite[ctr].facingDirection == 1)
    {
        SampleSprite[ctr].moveAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 0, 100 ) );
        SampleSprite[ctr].stoppingAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 10, 0 ) );
    }
    else if(SampleSprite[ctr].facingDirection == 2)
    {
        SampleSprite[ctr].moveAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 0, -100 ) );
        SampleSprite[ctr].stoppingAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 10, 0 ) );
    }
    else if(SampleSprite[ctr].facingDirection == 3)
    {
        SampleSprite[ctr].moveAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( -100, 0 ) );
        SampleSprite[ctr].stoppingAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 0,10 ) );
    }
    else if(SampleSprite[ctr].facingDirection == 4)
    {
        SampleSprite[ctr].moveAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 100, 0 ) );
        SampleSprite[ctr].stoppingAction = cocos2d::MoveBy::create( RANDOM NUMBER FROM 2-5, cocos2d::Vec2( 0, 10 ) );
    }

    SampleSprite[ctr].moveStopAction = cocos2d::Sequence::create(SampleSprite[ctr].moveAction, SampleSprite[ctr].stoppingAction, nullptr);
    SampleSprite[ctr].characterSprite->runAction( SampleSprite[ctr].moveStopAction );
}
else    // currently executing action
{
        if(SampleSprite[ctr].moveStopAction->isDone())          // check if done executing action
        {
            SampleSprite[ctr].isStillOnAction = false;          
        }
}}
```

**Result:**
It runs the **sequence action** but after that it **freezes** then it **crashes**.

**What is the possible problem that I overlooked?**

Thank you in advance smile

Answer (score 0):

Running actions inside a scheduled function will not crash the app. The problem is likely to be:

1. the action has be released when you use `.isDone()`. When a action is done, it will decrease its reference count and be released unless you have retained it ( not recommended).
2. `MoveBy::create()` returns an auto-release object, which means if you don't call `runAction` on it or retain it, it will be released at the end of this frame.

You can use tags to check whether an action is running:

```
static const int MY_MOVEBY_ACTION = 3333;
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++){
if(!SpriteSample[ctr].characterSprite->getActionByTag(MY_MOVE_ACTION))          // not currently executing action, so we can now assign an action
{
    SampleSprite[ctr].isStillOnAction = true;   // the isStillOnAction boolean is changed to true

    //......

    SampleSprite[ctr].moveStopAction = cocos2d::Sequence::create(SampleSprite[ctr].moveAction, SampleSprite[ctr].stoppingAction, nullptr);
    moveStopAction->setTag(MY_MOVE_ACTION);
    SampleSprite[ctr].characterSprite->runAction( SampleSprite[ctr].moveStopAction );
}
else    // currently executing action
{
        if(SampleSprite[ctr].moveStopAction->isDone())          // check if done executing action
        {
            SampleSprite[ctr].isStillOnAction = false;          
        }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I seem to try to fix it the other way using sequence, how to call another void function inside the sequence?

Comment: `Action::setCallbackFunc`?@nightrobin